# How can I optimize sql query for count rows with OR in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a SQL query to count the number of rows. I am using IN and OR in WHERE clause.
The current query is taking a long time (approx 10 sec.) to execute. Please help me to optimize the SQL query.
I am sharing my code:

````
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  booking_status_journey bs
  INNER JOIN booking_indonesia b ON b.id = bs.booking
WHERE
  bs.hid IN (
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    11,
    14,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26
  )
  AND (
    (
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(bs.picked_up_fromwh, '%d/%m/%Y')) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-15')
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(bs.picked_up_fromwh, '%d/%m/%Y')) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB('2020-10-15', INTERVAL 5 DAY))
      AND b.no_show_count = 0
      AND bs.rabbit_id1 IS NOT NULL
      AND bs.parcel_picked1 IS NULL
      AND bs.start_delivery1 IS NULL
      AND bs.arrived_at_drop_off1 IS NULL
      AND bs.delivered IS NULL
    )
    OR (
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(bs.picked_up_fromwh, '%d/%m/%Y')) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-15')
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(bs.picked_up_fromwh, '%d/%m/%Y')) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB('2020-10-15', INTERVAL 5 DAY))
      AND b.no_show_count = 1
      AND bs.rabbit_id2 IS NOT NULL
      AND bs.parcel_picked2 IS NULL
      AND bs.no_show1 IS NOT NULL
      AND bs.start_delivery2 IS NULL
      AND bs.arrived_at_drop_off2 IS NULL
      AND bs.delivered IS NULL
      AND bs.failed IS NULL
      AND bs.returned_after_failed IS NULL
      AND bs.returned_after_no_show1 IS NULL
      AND bs.returned_towh IS NULL
    )
  )```



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPDTG.png
````

Comment: I imagine all those columns are in one of the tables in the `from` clause.  And, optimizing the query certainly depends on where the columns are defined.  I would suggest that you edit the question and qualify all the column references.

Comment: Can you add EXPLAIN in front of the query and then run it? And can you put the outcome here in the question? There we can see what can be optimized like adding INDEXES

Comment: What indexes are defined on the table is important, but OR queries sometimes cannot use indexes. I would try separating it into 2 queries then sum the results.

Comment: You can little improve performance prevent `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. Something like `STR_TO_DATE(bs.picked_up_fromwh, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '2020-10-15'`